# Google ML kit or AR Core into Arduino or Raspberry PI

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, arcore, google-mlkit, arcore-limitation

Hi im currently doing my research on how accurate AR Core or Google's ML kit in terms of object recognition. But one of our requirements was to have an hardware like arduino or raspberry PI is there a way i can integrate the ML kit into the arduino? Sorry for newb question but thank you in advance!

I know that AR Core only supports android and my research aims to use this in an android panel for vehicles and a camera which will be both connected into arduino or raspberry PI but as I research more i think there are a lot of issues using these components together

Answer (score 0):

Google MLKit only supports android. There are some resources on the internet about how to programming arduino with android app: https://www.electromaker.io/blog/article/best-android-arduino-ides-for-programming-arduino-with-android
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/communicate-with-your-arduino-through-android/